# OnMetadataCreated executes multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am setting custom attributes to secure objects within a view. Here is the definition for my custom attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SecureObjectAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        if(!metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("isSecure"))
        {
            if (ObjectId == 1)
            {
                metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("isSecure", true);
            }
            else
            {
                metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("isSecure", false);
            }
        }
    }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my View Model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    [SecureObject(ObjectId = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am defining helpers for Secure Labels and Secure TextBoxes. Here are my helper functions:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString SecureLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        if ((bool)metadata.AdditionalValues["isSecure"])
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return html.LabelFor(expression);
        }
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SecureTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        if ((bool)metadata.AdditionalValues["isSecure"])
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return html.TextBoxFor(expression);
        }
    }
```

All of this works correctly, however, the problem that I am having is that every time I define a secure label and a secure textbox, the OnMetadataCreated method is invoked.

I am making a trip to the database on the OnMetadataCreated method (not shown in the example) to get permissions for the object, and I want to avoid duplicate trips for a single object.

The following is an example of code that is causing the OnMetadataCreated to be invoked twice in my View:

```
    @Html.SecureLabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.SecureTextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Any suggestions on how I can avoid a second call to the OnMetadataCreated method, or avoid a duplicate trip to the database?

Comment: On what variables does the call to the database depend? What are the arguments you are passing to your query and how do they vary between the users and sessions?

Comment: The calls to the database depend on the ObjectId, and the current logged in user. I get the isSecure value from the database.

Comment: How do you get the currently logged in user inside the `OnMetadataCreated` method?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the result of the execution of the query in the HttpContext to avoid roundtrips to the database within the same request:

```
public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
{
    // TODO: if you are using a DI framework you could pass the context
    // as a constructor argument dependency and use HttpContextBase
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

    bool isSecure;
    string key = "isSecure_" + ObjectId;
    if (context.Items.Contains(key))
    {
        // The isSecure value was found in the HttpContext => 
        // no need to query the database once again within this request
        isSecure = (bool)context.Items[key];
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the value from the database
        isSecure = GetFromDb(context.User.Identity.Name, ObjectId);
        // and store into the HttpContext to avoid roundtrips to the database
        // within this request
        context.Items[key] = isSecure;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This will not work for me if I have multiple items in my ViewModel which I want secure.
If I add the [SecureObject(ObjectId = 2)] on top of the Address object in my ViewModel, and in my View, I add:
    @Html.SecureLabelFor(m => m.Address)
    @Html.SecureTextBoxFor(m => m.Address)

Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make a complex key in which you could include the `ObjectId`. So instead of using `context.Items["isSecure"]` use `context.Items["isSecure_" + ObjectId]`. I have updated my answer to illustrate that. Now you will be hitting the database on the same request for each unique `ObjectId` for which the helpers are used.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are trying to do here. The problem I am getting now is that my helper functions are defined as static and my ObjectId's are defined as attributes in the ViewModel. How will I get the ObjectId in the helpers? I just want to render Label or Textboxes which are Non-Secure.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. I left my helpers code as is, and just added the metadata on every call. If there was an entry in the current context, I do not make a trip to the database anymore! Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.